# Simple regex negation

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Trying to match ONLY the first character in the sample below.

Sample string: `C/C++/Objective C/Objective-C/ObjectiveC/objectiveC`

My faulty regex: `(?![O|o]bjective[ |-]?)C(?!\+\+)`

Doh.

Comment: Btw, you haven't mentioned which regex engine you are using. Not all engines support the same features, so you should always specify what you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<![Oo]bjective[ -]?)C(?!\+\+)
```

Corrections are:

- Use negative lookbehind instead of negative lookahead (the `(?<!`...`)` bit).
- Removed pipe character from character classes (the `[`...`]` bits).

It might also be worth adding a pair of `\b`s either side of the `C`, since your current regex will match `Coconut`, `BBC`, `CFML` and so on

Also worth pointing out that, inside character classes, the `-` is special if not the first or last character. Some people prefer to escape it even in these situations, i.e. `[ \-]`, in case a later character is accidentally added after it.